# I need to convert an int parameter into a linked list field

Tags: c++

I created a link list and an integer field to represent the linked list.
Then I assigned the integer field to 0.
I don't know how to convert the int parameter into the linked list.

```
template<typename T>
struct Node{
  T data;
  Node* next;
};

class Integer{
private:
  Node<int>* real_num;

public:
    
Integer(){
   real_num->data = 0;
   std::cout << "success!";
}

Integer(int int_convert){
   real_num->data = int_convert;
}
```

Comment: Write a linked list class to manage the links. To the linked list class add an `insert` method that adds nodes to the list for you. Then all `Integer` needs to do is break up the `int` according to rules you have not given us and call the `insert` method with the chunks. Poke around on Stack Overflow and you will find thousands of questions about how to write a decent linked list. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) should be an excellent source as well as the linked lists there will have been picked over and corrected by experts.

Comment: Even better, use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) or [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) instead of rolling your own linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor assigns a value to a variable in a structure which has been declared but not itself constructed.

Add this to the top of your constructors.

```
Node<int> * real_num=new Node<int>;
```

Only after the Node has had memory allocated, etc is it valid to reference a variable in the struct that real_num only points to. Without 'new' real_num points to null.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) which is a container that represents a double-linked list.

If it doesn't answer your problem, <s>so far your code is correct</s>. You now need to add [getter and setter](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_encapsulation.asp) and also utility functions to manipulate your linked list.

**Edit:** You have to construct your private variable before using it or will run into a *undefined behavior* because you gonna use a memory part that hasn't been initialized. If you are lucky enough, your program will crash and end up with a `Segmentation Fault`.

Take a look at the keyword [new and delete](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) to allocate/deallocate memory in C++.

Comment: I just rechecked my comment and its code, saw the missing part ; I directly edited my answer. I can not downvote posts and helping people is a competition or what?
Moreover, both comments highlight the same problem but describe it differently and the two responses complement each other.